# Vertical aligning a Unicode symbol within a textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a use-case where I need to use the unicode down-arrowhead and up-arrowhead symbols at the end of a sentence in a textView.

This is the simplest form of the problem I have

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.symbols);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Small X0 ▲ ▼ <br/> Small X1 <small>▲ ▼</small> <br/> Small X2 <small><small>▲ ▼</small></small><br/> Small X3 <small><small><small>▲ ▼</small></small></small>".toUpperCase()));
```

▲ -> \u25B2

▼ -> \u25BC

This is how the view shows up.

[image]

The `SMALL X3` is what I want, but the arrows are "floored" down in that line. Is it possible to somehow make that centered with respect to the text?

I've tried the "smaller" versions on the triangles, but when they are rendered in android, the sizes of the 2 triangles are not the same. Hence, I am using the `<small></small>` tags to get what I want.

Edit: Forgot to add a piece of information. The text can be more than one line and the arrows should be at the end of the sentence. This removes the possibility of having 2 `TextView`s in a LinearLayout. Below represents the a possible scenario

```
----------------------------------------------
| THIS IS A LONG SENTENCE AND IT OVERFLOWS   |
| TO THE NEXT LINE. ▲ ▼                      |
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Still not answered, but the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939352/vertical-aligning-a-unicode-symbol-within-a-textview

Comment: Same problem here...